# ssl certificate breaks Android app and web service

Tags: android, iis, ssl, https

I need to renew an SSL certificate which uses SHA1 with a new certificate which uses SHA256. However, when I apply the certificate our Android App which calls some https pages and a Web Service which is also accessed over HTTPS both fail to connect. If I swap to the old certificate, the App and Web Service work fine again.

I have checked the certificate chain using an SSL analyser and that shows each cert in the chain being sent by the server.

To apply the new certificate always requires a full server reboot and not just an IIS restart, however to swap back to the old one just needs an IIS restart. So I'm not sure if something else is being changed by the cert?

It's quite hard to test as I can't leave these 2 services offline for very long unless there is another way to test this I haven't thought of?

Any help much appreciated!